# How do I SELECT all the entries in a SQL table that have a date within the last week but only if the EQNum has not appeared in the past 6 months

Tags: sql-server

I am very much a SQL novice.  I am looking to write a script that will select all the columns from a table where two criteria are met:

1. The date of the call must have happened within the past 7 days
2. The EQNum must not have had another call placed on it in the past six months

Here is a sample table:

```
Call, Date,       EQNum, Customer

123,  06-16-2015, 75,     ABC Co
125,  06-16-2015, 82,     XYZ Co
133,  06-14-2015, 69,     DEF Co
101,  05-12-2015, 82,     XYZ Co
115,  10-11-2014, 69,     DEF Co
```

The query I need created should return:

```
123, 06-16-2015, 75, ABC Co 
133, 06-14-2015, 69, DEF Co
```

The Call 125 (EQNum 82) is eliminated because though is occurred in the past week, EQNum 82 had another call (Call 101) occur within the last 6 month thus eliminating it.

Call 133 is valid because the other call for EQNum 69 occurred more than 6 months ago.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
from tbl
WHERE DateCol > DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                FROM tbl this 
                WHERE this.EQNum = tbl.EQNum 
                    AND this.DateCol > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
               )
```

Comment: "The date of the call must have happened within the past 7 days"

Comment: updated to include last 7 days, and sub query within the last 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, although it probably wouldn't perform well if the table got massive

```
select
  Call, 
  [Date], 
  EQNum, 
  Customer
from #table
where 
  [Date] > getdate() - 7 and
  EQNum not in 
  (
    select
      EQNum
    from #table
    where
      [Date] > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
    group by
       EQNum
    having count(*) > 1
  )
```

Another way would be to left join...

```
select
  Call, 
  [Date], 
  EQNum, 
  Customer
from #table t1
  left join #table t2 on
    t1.Call != t2.Call and
    t1.EQNum = t2.EQNum and
    t2.Date > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
where
  t1.[Date] > getdate() - 7 and
  t2.Call is null
```